# Why is the operation of differentiation called "instantaneous change"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is said that

> Differentiation is an operation which finds the **instantaneous** change of the direction of a curve.

Why is the word **change** emphasized by the word **instantaneous**?

Comment: Can you link to a specific place where this phrasing appears? The derivative $f'(t)$ is the instantaneous *rate* of change of $f$ at time $t$.

Comment: Your quote is wrong. Differentiation gives the _direction_ of the curve. The derivative is the instantaneous change in _position_ or _value_  (the second derivative gives the change in direction).

Comment: Well it's not emphasised by it. The meaning is clarified by it. Do you mean "Why not just *change*", or "why is it described in terms of time?"

Comment: It’s commonly described as the instantaneous *rate* of change.

Comment: It is in opposition to the ‘average change’ of direction.

Comment: @Bernard, you are on topic here. Kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by “change in direction” you mean “slope”, that’s precisely what a derivative is. It’s not emphasizing anything, that’s simply the *definition* of a derivative, as opposed to the average slope between two points.

For the average slope across two points $(x, f(x))$ and $((x+h), f(x+h))$, or the slope of the secant, you have

$$m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

However, as you let $h \to 0$, the secant approaches a tangent line and you find the derivative *at the point* (hence the term “instantaneous”), so you get

$$m = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

For instance, differentiating $f(x) = x^2$ gives $f’(x) = 2x$, meaning the slope of the tangent that touches the curve at $x$ will have the slope $2x$.

As a real-life example, if the displacement of a car is given by the same function $s(t) = t^2$, then the **instantaneous** velocity of the car at any $t$ will be $2t$. As an example, at $t = 5$, $v = 10$.